# Postgres container continuously restarting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

For my local Rails development, I'm using a postgres database setup from the standard docker image. However, I made the mistake of running `docker build .`. Now when I try to bring the postgres container up, I get an error:

```
db_1   | initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
db_1   | It contains a dot-prefixed/invisible file, perhaps due to it being a mount point.
db_1   | Using a mount point directly as the data directory is not recommended.
db_1   | Create a subdirectory under the mount point.
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.2'
volumes:
  pg_data:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0'
    env_file:
      - variables.env
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

and `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /my_app
WORKDIR /my_app
ADD Gemfile /my_app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /my_app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /my_app
```

I was hoping to re-use my data I've accumulated to this point. If I need to start from scratch locally, so be it, I suppose I'd have to delete the persisted volume if I wanted to do that. I'm not quite sure to be honest. I'm not too worried about this occurring on my production server as we're using an actual Postgres installation on a server.

Directory tree:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM                app
d-----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM                bin
d-----       2018-02-12   4:28 PM                config
d-----       2018-02-12   4:28 PM                db
d-----       2017-07-27  11:43 AM                lib
d-----       2017-08-31   2:51 PM                log
d-----       2018-01-18   1:35 PM                pg_data
d-----       2018-02-01   2:09 PM                public
d-----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM                test
d-----       2017-07-26  10:35 AM                tmp
d-----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM                vendor
-a----       2017-07-31   9:56 AM             14 .byebug_history
-a----       2018-02-12   4:28 PM            605 .gitignore
-a----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM            130 config.ru
-a----       2018-11-13  11:32 AM            478 docker-compose.yml
-a----       2019-07-19   8:54 AM            521 Dockerfile
-a----       2019-08-09   2:41 PM           2297 Gemfile
-a----       2018-02-12   4:28 PM           6434 Gemfile.lock
-a----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM             71 package.json
-a----       2017-07-26   9:52 AM            227 Rakefile
-a----       2019-05-30   1:49 PM            599 README.md
-a----       2017-12-12   9:50 AM             92 variables.env
```

EDIT/UPDATE

**LESSON LEARNED:** Don't break anything on a Friday under an hour before leaving for the weekend... lol

UPDATE 2:
Added directory tree

UPDATE 3:
Rebooting appears to have done something as the database/postgres container can start up properly. However, my previous data does not appear to have persisted. I'm guessing it's an issue related to my volume configuration/setup but not quite sure.

Comment: would you pls also attach the directory tree of `pg_data`? it seems pg could not recognize the mounted volume as a correct pg data volume.

Comment: Added a directory tree as requested by @Enix

Comment: Looked like rebooting did something as the database container does start up but my persisted data does not appear.

Comment: What about the files inside pg_data? Are u using the same postgres version?

Comment: I'm not sure why but I don't see any files in that directory except for a stub file called `.keep` just so the directory is included in our version control. Come to think about it, I don't think I've ever seen any files there but the data was always retained when I ran `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` so I'm not sure if I correctly understanding how persistence and volumes works. @Enix

Comment: you can’t place any file or dir inside pg_data except the file/dir created by postgres. You can copy the entire data dir from production, and try to run it again